# Finding the number of ways of T.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{1,2,3...32\}$ and

$T=\{x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4} \in S^4  \mid x_2  \geq x_1+2, x_3 \geq x_2, x_4\geq x_3 + 4\}$

Find the $\mid T\mid $

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_2 - x_1 -2 = a$, $x_3 - x_2 = b $, $x_4 - x_3 -4 = c$,
From the equations we get that $$0 \leq a+b+c \leq 25$$.
Let $a+b+c =k$, number of solutions = ${k+2 \choose 2} $
and for each solution there are $32-(k+6)$ options (to choose $x_1$,rest are then fixed).
So,total solutions are $$\sum_{k=0}^{k=25}{k+2 \choose 2}*(32-(k+6))$$